# CDF of $\frac{X_1X_2}{X_1+X_2+a}$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ have exp. distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent exponential random variables with the PDFs $f_{X_1}(x_1)=\lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1 x_1)$ and $f_{X_2}(x_2)=\lambda_2 \exp(-\lambda_2 x_2)$.

Let $X= \frac{X_1X_2}{X_1+X_2+a}$ be a r.v. for which I want to derive the CDF, where $a$ is a positive constant.

In other words, I need to calculate $\mathbb{P}\{X <x \}$.

Any ideas or hints?

**Edit (attempt):** 
Using a similar approach to that used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333286/find-cumulative-distribution-function-of-two-independent-exponential-random-vari), we have $X_1 \in [0, \infty)$ and  $X_2 \in [0, \frac{x(x_1+a)}{x_1-x})$. The latter interval results from: $\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2+a} < x$, thus $x_2(x_1-x)<x(x_1+a)$ which implies $x_2 < \frac{x(x_1+a)}{x_1-x}$; but I am not sure if this is correct since $x_1-x$ can sometimes be negative (?). Based on the above, we can write: \begin{align}
 \mathbb{P} \{ \frac{X_1X_2}{X_1+X_2+a} < x \}  & = \int_{x_1=0}^\infty \int_{x_2=0}^{ \frac{x(x_1+a)}{x_1-x}} \lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1 x_1) \lambda_2 \exp(-\lambda_2 x_2)  dx_2 dx_1  \\ &= \int_{x_1=0}^\infty \left(1-\exp(-\lambda_2\frac{x(x_1+a)}{x_1-x}) \right) \lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1 x_1) dx_1  \\ & = 1-\lambda_1 \int_{x_1=x}^\infty \exp(-\lambda_2\frac{x(x_1+a)}{x_1-x} ) \exp(-\lambda_1 x_1)   dx_1
\end{align}
In the last equality: for the integral of $\lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1 x_1) dx_1$, I suppose that $x_1 \in [0,\infty)$, whereas for the second term I suppose that $x_1 \ge x$ (since $x_2$ should be positive) (?).

Is my approach correct ?

Comment: If the function has a one to one mapping with the component random variables, ie, there exist only countably finite $X_1,X_2$ for each value of the random variable $X$, then it's just a matter of adding possible values for $X_i's$ Will add calculations as soon as I reach home from work.

Comment: It is easier to find $P(X>x)$ after you sketch the plane and mark on it the region where $X$ exceeds the given fixed value of $x$.

Comment: @Giridhur Unfortunately these are continuous random variables and so your method won't work

Comment: Why is that unfortunate? Do continuous rv's not have feelings too? I was looking forwards to the workings ...

Comment: @DilipSarwate Maybe I misunderstood you, but the value of $x$ is not known. Could you please provide more details on how I can calculate the probability ?

Comment: If we conisder $x_1 \in [0,\infty)$, and based on $\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2+a}<x$, we have $x_2(x_1-x) < xx_1+ax$, or equivalently $x_2 < \frac{x(x_1+a)}{x_1-x}$. But I am not sure if this is correct since I don't know if $x_1-x$ is positive or not.

Comment: You have to calculate $P(X>x)$ for _each_ choice of real number $x$ and so during the calculation of the value of  $P(X>x)$, $x$ is a fixed number. You have to repeat the basic calculation for different choices of $x$ (you can choose!) until such time as lightning strikes and you shout out something like "Hey, Ma! I think I am beginning to see a pattern here! No matter what $x > 5$ I have chosen, $P(X>x) = e^{-ax}$ while for $x$ between $0$ and $5$, $P(X>x)$ equals $\cdots$"

Comment: @wolfies I too am eager to see how Giridhur adds up a finite or countably infinite  possible values of $X_1$ and $X_2$ (or their probabilities) to arrive at a value for $X$ (or the probability of $X$).

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am sorry but still have not got your idea. Please note that I have added an attempt to my question. Could you please check it and tell me if it is correct ?

Comment: That the upper bound $\frac{x(x_1+a)}{x_1-x}$ of the integral is sometimes negative shows the formula you suggest canot be correct. Instead, consider $$Y=\frac{X_1X_2}{X_1+X_2+a}$$ and, for every $y>0$, use the identity of events $$[Y<y]=[X_1\leqslant y]\cup[X_1>y,X_2<y(X_1+a)(X_1-y)^{-1}]$$ hence $$P(Y<y]=P[X_1\leqslant y]+\int_y^\infty P[X_2<y(x+a)(x-y)^{-1}]f_{X_1}(x)dx$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: @Did $P(Y<y)=1-\exp(-\lambda_1y)+ \lambda_1  \int_y^\infty \left(1-\exp(-\lambda_2 y(x+a)(x-y)^{-1}) \right) \exp(-\lambda_1 x) dx =$ $1-\exp(-\lambda_1y)+\exp(-\lambda_1y)- \lambda_1 \int_y^\infty \exp(-\lambda_2 y(x+a)(x-y)^{-1}) \exp(-\lambda_1 x) dx =$ $\\ 1 - \int_y^\infty \exp(-\lambda_2 y(x+a)(x-y)^{-1}) \exp(-\lambda_1 x) dx$.                                 Is it correct ? if so, it can be seen that this is the same result  I have obtained using my approach (yet I have considered a bound that can be negative).

Comment: @Did I think I am getting the same result in my apporach because in the last equality I change the bounds of integration so that $x_1-x$ stays positive; i.e. $x_1 \ge x$.   As for the rest of the derivations: let $u=x-y$, thus:  the integral becomes:  $\lambda_1 \int_{u=0}^\infty \exp(-\lambda_2 y(u+y+a)(u)^{-1}) \exp(-\lambda_1 (u+y) du=$ $\lambda_1 \exp(-(\lambda_1+ \lambda_2)y)  \int_{u=0}^\infty  \exp(-\lambda_2 y(y+a)(u)^{-1}) \exp(-\lambda_1 u) du$. I think this (last) integral can be written in function of a special function. Am I correct ?

Comment: "I think I am getting the same result in my apporach because in the last equality I change the bounds of integration so that $x_1−x$ stays positive" Indeed this step in your computations is particularly unconvincing. To complete the computation of $P(Y<y)$, I would start from the change of variable $x=y+z$ in the last integral, which yields $$P(Y<y)=1-e^{-\lambda_1y}+\int_0^\infty P(X_2<y+(x+a)/z)\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1(y+z)}dz$$

Comment: @Did I agree.. Let us forget my approach (given in the question). In my last comments, I have done the derivations based on your approach and have considered the change of variables $u=x-y$ after computing the integral $\lambda_1 \int_y^\infty \exp(-\lambda_1 x) dx$ (instead of considering the change of variable from the beginning); anw I think it yields the same result.

Comment: @Did Please note that you can write your answer (even if it is not detailed) so that I can accept it. One last question please: I am trying to find the CDF of $X_1+\frac{b X_2}{X_2+a}$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distributions as given in the former case, and where $a$ and $b$ are some positive constants. My question: do you think that I should ask this as an independent question or the answer can be deduced from the answer to the former case? thank you so much!

Comment: Alternatively, you could develop the indications I gave and post the result as an answer to your own question. After a while, and if the community seems to think your answer is valuable, you might accept it.

Comment: @Did I have posted an answer. Please give me your feedback.

Comment: Done. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the indications that @Did gave, I was able to derive the CDF of $Y=\frac{X_1X_2}{X_1+X_2+a}$ (note that in the question I use $X$ instead of $Y$) as follows:

Based on the identity of events 
\begin{align}
\left[ Y <y \right] = \left[ X_1 < y \right] \cup \left[ X_1 \ge y, X_2 < y (X_1+a)(X_1-y)^{-1} \right],
\end{align}
we get the following
\begin{align}
\nonumber \mathbb{P} \{ Y < y \} &= \mathbb{P}\{X_1 <y\}+ \int_y^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X_2 < y (x+a) (x-y)^{-1} \} f_{X_1}(x) \, dx \\ \nonumber &= 1-e^{-\lambda_1y} + \lambda_1 \int_y^\infty (1-e^{-\lambda_2 y(x+a)(x-y)^{-1}}) e^{-\lambda_1 x} dx \\ \nonumber &= 1-e^{-\lambda_1y}+e^{-\lambda_1y}- \lambda_1 \int_y^\infty  e^{-\lambda_2 y(x+a)(x-y)^{-1}} e^{-\lambda_1 x} dx \\ \nonumber & =_{(i)}  1- \lambda_1 \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{ -\lambda_2 y(u+y+a)u^{-1}} e^{-\lambda_1 (u+y)} du \\ \nonumber  &= 1- \lambda_1 e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)y} \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda_2 y (y+a)u^{-1}} e^{-\lambda_1u} du \\ & =_{(ii)} 1- \lambda_1 e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)y} \, 2 \, \sqrt{ y(y+a) \lambda_2 \lambda_1^{-1} } \, K_1\left(2 \sqrt{  y(y+a) \lambda_2 \lambda_1  } \right),
 \\ & = 1- e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)y} \, 2 \, \sqrt{ y(y+a) \lambda_2 \lambda_1 } \, K_1\left(2 \sqrt{  y(y+a) \lambda_2 \lambda_1  } \right)
\end{align}
in which equality (i) is due to the change of variable $u=x-y$ and equality (ii) follows from [Table of Integrals, Series and Products, 7th edition - equation 3.471.9].

Comment: You are correct. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yes. What remains is a success story for this site, it seems... Simply wait a little while before accepting your own answer, to let other people react to it if they wish to.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote two independent  exponential random variables and suppose that $V = \frac{XY}{X+Y+a}$ where $a > 0$. What is the CDF of $V$?

First, note that $V > 0$. Let $v$ denote a positive constant, and let us try to determine the *complementary* CDF $P\{V > v\}$ by integrating the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ over that part of the first quadrantVwhere $V$ exceeds $v$.  The set in question, call it $A$, is given by
\begin{align}
A  &= \{(x,y)\colon x > 0, y > 0, \frac{xy}{x+y+a} > v\}\\
&= \{(x,y)\colon x > 0, y > 0, xy > v(x+y+a)\}\\
&= \{(x,y)\colon x > 0, y > 0, xy -vx -vy > av\}\\
&= \{(x,y)\colon x > 0, y > 0, (x-v)(y-v) > v^2 + av\}.
\end{align}
Now, the graph of the *hyperbola* $xy = b$ consists of two curves confined to the first and third quadrants respectively and passing through the points $\left(\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{b}\right)$ and $\left(-\sqrt{b}, -\sqrt{b}\right)$ respectively. Therefore,  the graph of $(x-v)(y-v) = b$ is just these two curves shifted to the right by $v$ and shifted upwards by $v$, and the two curves now pass through $(\sqrt{b}+v, \sqrt{b}+v)$ and $(-\sqrt{b}+v, -\sqrt{b}+v)$ respectively.  Note that the asymptotes of the curves are $x=v, y=v$. Now, when $b$ equals $v^2+av$, $\sqrt{b} > v$ and so the point $(-\sqrt{b}+v, -\sqrt{b}+v)$ is in the third quadrant. Consequently, the lower branch of the hyperbola does not lie in the first quadrant at all.  (It *does* cross the $x$ and $y$ axes into the second and fourth quadrants but that is immaterial in this problem). It follows that we can express $A$ as
$$A = \{(x,y)\colon x > v, y > v, (x-v)(y-v) > v^2 + av\}.$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
1-F_V(v) &= P((X,Y)\in A)\\
&= \iint_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx\\
&= \int_v^\infty f_X(x) \left[ \int_{y = \frac{v^2+av}{x-v}}^\infty f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy \right] \, \mathrm dx.
\end{align}
The inner integral is straightforward to evaluate; the outer one is trickier, needing special functions and tables of integrals to
evaluate.

An alternative calculation given in an answer by the OP (with the
help of many suggestions from @Did) directly evaluates
the CDF $P\{V \leq v\}$ by partitioning the set under consideration
into the events $\{X \leq v\}$ and $\left\{X>v, 0 < Y \leq  v\frac{x+a}{x-v}\right\}$.